# Reset A6 GPRS module wirelessly

Tags: arduino, at-command, gprs

In A6 GPRS module I read this sentence:

> Can use SMS to config module

What does it means exactly?

Can I set my module setting with AT commands through SMS?
That's why I ask because I need reset my Arduino board in wireless (not access to internet, only GSM).

Has anyone any idea?

Answer (score 0):

> Can use SMS to config module

This means a special sms can be used to get the settings needed to activate the Internet/data/GPRS on the module. The network provider can usually send you one via USSD request or you can craft one yourself but the specifications can be arcane.